# Convert std::filesystem::file_time_type to epoch nanoseconds?

Tags: c++, casting, c++-chrono

I'm trying to read a file's last modified date/time and convert it into nanoseconds (I guess microseconds would be enough as well) using C++20.

Here are my attempts:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path myFile("D:\\myfile.png");
    if (std::filesystem::exists(myFile)) {
      std::filesystem::file_time_type ftime = std::filesystem::last_write_time(myFile);
      auto epoch = ftime.time_since_epoch();
      auto nano = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(epoch).count();
      const auto systemTime = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(ftime);
      const auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(systemTime);
      std::cout << std::format("ftime: {}\nepoch: {}\nnano: {}\nsystemtime: {}\ntime: {}\n", ftime, epoch, nano, systemTime, time);
    }
    else {
      std::cerr << "File does not exist." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

The output is:

```
ftime: 2021-11-15 08:54:38.5861611
epoch: 132814400785861611[1/10000000]s
nano: -5165303995123390516
systemtime: 2021-11-15 08:54:38.5861611
time: 1636966478
```

- `ftime` is the correct time as shown for the file
- `epoch` and `nano` are invalid dates, however.
- `systemTime` seems to have converted it back? But in the debugger, `systemTime` seems to have the correct value ("16369664785861611")
- `time` is the closest, but it's not precise enough.

Sadly I'm can't wrap my head around how to use the casting of `std::chrono` and what the correct syntax is, so I would appreciate some help on figuring out where I'm wrong.

Comment: Try to use `std::uint_64` for your `nano`. Also, tried it quickly in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h8dPhM18o) and cannot repro.

Comment: Keep in mind that `time_since_epoch` is relative to the clock's epoch, which is often, but not necessarily, the UNIX epoch (midnight 1/1/1970).  In particular, the Windows file time epoch is different (midnight 1/1/1601).  The `clock_cast` implementation knows this, but a simple `time_since_epoch` will look wrong since you're comparing it to the wrong epoch.

Comment: @pptaszni Thank you for your reply! That code works but is not really what I was asking. Changing `auto nano` to `std::uint64_t` did not change anything.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Hmm, that might be it since I'm on Windows. I still can't get it to work though.

Comment: Have you tried `duation_cast<nanoseconds>(systemTime.time_since_epoch()).count()`?  I don't have a Windows box handy, but I expect that would give you what you want.

Comment: @MilesBudnek answer is correct and I've upvoted it.  I just wanted to add that your `nano` is garbage because it is trying to represent the number of nanoseconds since the Windows file_time epoch (1601-01-01) and 2021-11-15, which overflows the 64 bit range for nanoseconds (+/- 292 years).  Other than `nano`, all of your output looks correct to me.  `epoch` is the number of Windows ticks (`[1/10000000]s`) since the Windows file_time epoch (1601-01-01).

Answer (score 3):

The epoch used by Windows file times is not the UNIX epoch.  Windows file times use an epoch of midnight UTC on January 1, 1601, as opposed to the UNIX epoch of midnight UTC on January 1, 1970.

That means that the epoch of the `std::filesystem::file_time_type` on Windows is not the UNIX epoch, so your `time_since_epoch` call is returning the time since the Windows file epoch, not the UNIX epoch.

When you do your `clock_cast` the time gets adjusted to the UNIX epoch, since thats what `std::chrono::system_clock` uses.  That means that getting the count of nanoseconds since your `systemTime` `time_point`'s epoch should give you the answer you want:

```
auto timeSinceUnixEpoch = systemTime.time_since_epoch();
uint64_t nanosSinceUnixEpoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(timeSinceUnixEpoch).count();
```

Keep in mind that you will not get full nanosecond precision though, since NTFS stores times with a precision of 100s of nanoseconds.

Comment: Thank you, that works! So do I understand that correctly: to get the correct time, I have to cast the time of the file (`file_time_type`) to `system_clock`. Then convert that to the time since the start of the right date (1601 under Linux, 1970 for Windows). Finally cast it to microseconds. Is that correct? Also, why do I need to cast **and** `count` in the last step? Shouldn't `count()` already produce the nanoseconds?

Comment: `ftime` is a `time_point` on the `file_clock`, which measures time since 1601.  The `time_point` has no unit though; it's just a point in time (logically speaking).  You then have to `clock_cast` that to the `system_clock`, which measures time since 1970.  You still just have a point in time, but it's based on a different clock.

Comment: `time_since_epoch` then gives you the `duration` between the epoch of the clock (1970, in the case of `system_clock`) and your `time_point`, but it's unspecified what unit that duration is represented in.  You have to `duration_cast` it to get the correct unit.  It's still a `duration` though, you have to call `count` to convert it to a simple integral type.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this in detail!